# Is there a case that a heuristic approach to be guaranteed to provide optimal solution?

Tags: algorithm, terminology, heuristics

As it is said (e.g., Wikipedia) heuristics provide solution which are not guarantee to be optimal. I think this is true in many cases, but what if we use for example a heuristic cost estimation (like the one in A* algorithm) to achieve a solution which could be proven to be optimal. In that case shouldn't we refer to that algorithm as heuristics?

Comment: If there exists a problem instance in which the algorithm terminates without giving the optimal solution, then the algorithm is a heuristic. Finding solutions that could be proven optimal otherwise (by using an exact method) does not change the heuristic nature of the algorithm. As larsmans says below, if one can prove that an algorithm guarantees optimality at termination, given certain technical conditions, then the algorithm is exact. So it much depends on the conditions that frame the problem, if an algorithm is classified as a heuristic or not.

Comment: So, if I understood you and larsmans well, an exact algorithm which employs a heuristic function as part of it to prune fruitless branches of the search tree (which 100% don't lead to any optimal solution) couldn't be called heuristics. But what can I call it? Maybe "an exact algorithm equipped with a heuristic function"?

Comment: I would just call it exact algorithm, and if you need to elaborate further then what you said is also true.
The fact that it uses a heuristic part makes it more efficient in practice, nothing to do with exactness. Even if the heuristic is removed, the algorithm remains exact. By the way, exact does not mean "efficient", in the practical or mathematical sense. For instance, brute force enumeration is exact but not efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a heuristic cost estimation function that obeys certain laws, A* is an algorithm in the strict sense of a method of computation that always gives the right answer to a prespecified set of problems.(*) The fact that it *uses* a heuristic does not make A* itself a heuristic.

( * ) There are cases where the optimal path between A and B might not exist and A* will run forever; for such problems, A* is a semi-algorithm.